# glDrawElements crash (OpenGL 3.2 / Windows 7)

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-3, glm-math

I'm trying to draw a simple quad in OpenGL 3.2 however the application crashes with "Access violation reading location 0x00000000" when I call "glDrawElements".

I assume the issue is that the Vertex Buffer data is wrong, but I am unsure how to fix the issue / debug it (an OpenGL trace would be fantastic but I do not know how to enable this either...)

Initialization code:

```
std::vector<CUShort> Indices;
const CUShort IndicesArray[] = { 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 3 };

for(size_t j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(IndicesArray) / sizeof(*IndicesArray); i++) {
        Indices.push_back(4 * j + IndicesArray[i]);
    }
}

glGenBuffers(1, &m_Elements);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_Elements);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, Indices.size() * sizeof(CUShort), &Indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glGenVertexArrays(1, &m_Array);
glBindVertexArray(m_Array);

glGenBuffers(1, &m_Buffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_Buffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(TexColorVertex), NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_TRUE, sizeof(TexColorVertex), (const GLvoid*)offsetof(TexColorVertex, Color));

glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(TexColorVertex), (const GLvoid*)offsetof(TexColorVertex, Position));

glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(TexColorVertex), (const GLvoid*)offsetof(TexColorVertex, Texcoord));

glBindVertexArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

Drawing code:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_Buffer);

TexColorVertex Vertices[4];

glm::vec4 SpritePos = glm::vec4(0, 0, 1024.0f, 384.0f);
Vertices[0].Position = glm::vec2(SpritePos.x, SpritePos.y);
Vertices[1].Position = glm::vec2(SpritePos.x, SpritePos.w);
Vertices[2].Position = glm::vec2(SpritePos.z, SpritePos.w);
Vertices[3].Position = glm::vec2(SpritePos.z, SpritePos.y);

Color Kittens = Color::HotPink();
Vertices[0].Color = glm::vec4(Kittens.R(), Kittens.G(), Kittens.B(), 1.0f);
Vertices[1].Color = glm::vec4(Kittens.R(), Kittens.G(), Kittens.B(), 1.0f);
Vertices[2].Color = glm::vec4(Kittens.R(), Kittens.G(), Kittens.B(), 1.0f);
Vertices[3].Color = glm::vec4(Kittens.R(), Kittens.G(), Kittens.B(), 1.0f);

Vertices[0].Texcoord = glm::vec2(0.0f, 0.0f);
Vertices[1].Texcoord = glm::vec2(0.0f, 1.0f);
Vertices[2].Texcoord = glm::vec2(1.0f, 1.0f);
Vertices[3].Texcoord = glm::vec2(1.0f, 0.0f);

glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertices), sizeof(Vertices), Vertices);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_Elements);
glBindVertexArray(m_Array);

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (const GLvoid*)0);
```

The vertex struct is declared as such:

```
struct TexColorVertex
{
    TexColorVertex(void) { }
    TexColorVertex(glm::vec2 const& Position, glm::vec2 const& Texcoord) :
        Position(Position), Texcoord(Texcoord)
    { }
    glm::vec2 Position;
    glm::vec2 Texcoord;
    glm::vec4 Color;
};
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this and draw a simple quad that takes up half the screen?

Comment: You're sending `NULL` as the index array to `glDrawElements`

Comment: @JesusRamos I believe that's an offset. Opengl gets the index data from the currently bound element array buffer.

Comment: @Ben It's an array of offsets into the vertex array that was bound. In this case it should be an array of 6 indexes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While [user3256930](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3256930/user3256930) does bring up a valid point about the allocated size of your buffer, that is actually not the cause of your crash.

The problem is *not* with `glBufferSubData (...)`, but rather with the call to `glDrawElements (...)`. This call is attempting to dereference a **NULL** pointer, which is a red flag that nothing is bound to `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`.

When nothing is bound to `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`, then the pointer you pass to `glDrawElements (...)` is an actual pointer to *client memory* rather than an offset into Buffer Object (*server*) memory.

---

#### To understand why this occurs, recall what *Vertex Array Objects* store:

1. Vertex Attribute State [Pointers, Enable/Disable]
2. ***Element Array Buffer Binding*** (`GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`)

#### Now, consider the order of these two calls:

```
glBindBuffer      (GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_Elements);
glBindVertexArray (m_Array);
```

First you bind something to `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` (**m_Elements**) and immediately afterwards you bind a Vertex Array Object (**m_Array**), which replaces the element array buffer you just bound with the binding it keeps track of internally.

You should consider either **(1)** using your VAO to persistently reference a single element array buffer or **(2)** reversing the order of these two calls.

---

If your Vertex Array Object (**m_Array**) will always be used with the same element array buffer, then I would suggest you use the first approach. This can be implemented simply by moving the following code in your initialization:

```
glGenVertexArrays (1, &m_Array);
glBindVertexArray (m_Array);
```

To come ***before***:

```
glGenBuffers (1, &m_Elements);
glBindBuffer (GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_Elements);
glBufferData (GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, Indices.size() * sizeof(CUShort), &Indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

With this approach, nothing needs to be explicitly bound to `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` in your drawing code.

Comment: That gets rid of the crash at least, still isn't drawing anything but hopefully I can figure that part out :)

Answer (score 4):

You are not allocating enough space for your vertices in your call to glBufferData. You pass sizeof(TexColorVertex) which allocates space for 1 vertex. If you want to draw a quad then you need to allocate space for 4 vertices so you should change your call to glBuffer Data as follows:

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 4*sizeof(TexColorVertex), NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

That way when you make your subsequent calls to glBufferSubData you will not be attempting to access GPU memory that is out of range.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that when the buffer is allocated in this code, the size of the buffer is actually unknown. For this reason, it might be better simply to use `glBufferData (...)` in the ***drawing*** code to *orphan* the old buffer. No memory is going to leak, the old memory will be freed by GL as soon as there are no pending commands in the pipeline that reference it. In fact, this will probably give better performance anyway as it will not necessitate OpenGL to stall the pipeline or make copies of the buffer to prevent pending draw commands from using the wrong copy of data.

Comment: It all comes down to something known as implicit synchronization in GL. Since draw commands from multiple frames may still be incomplete when you call `glBufferSubData (...)`, in order to prevent this call from affecting previous frames GL has to do some synchronization behind the scenes. If instead of modifying the data of a buffer's ***existing*** memory every frame, you simply allocate new memory this prevents the possibility of modifying memory needed by a previous frame and vastly simplifies things. Again, nothing will leak because after no commands reference the old memory it is freed.

Comment: Also very correct, but since Andon M. Coleman's answer fixed the crashed I marked his response as the answer. Thanks for the help on this one however :)